# Error says Field Elements can only have 2- or 3-tuples and says I have 6 when I only have 2

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So apparently, Python thinks that my two-dimensional array (each dimension has a length of 5) is six-dimensional (or what I think it's saying).

Below, "td" is the two-dimensional array I have

```
import numpy as np
  
td = np.array([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10])

flattened = td.reshape([1, 10])

print(flattened)
```

and the error it gives is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: Field elements must be 2- or 3-tuples, got '6'
```

Comment: The problem is that the `[6,7,8,9,10]` list is in the `dtype` parameter slot.  You are passing `np.array` two lists, when it should only be one.  A valid list dtype would look something like : `np.array([1,2,3,4,5], dtype-[('foo',int)])`

Answer (score 0):

for creating two dim np array you need to add one more square bracket.

```
td=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
             [6,7,8,9,10]])
```

Comment: adding a new list with fixed values does not concretly perform this task because there are specific methods to manipulate or create 2d shape arrays or more https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#calculation